# matrix of matrix

Tags: tables

I want generate this structure:

```
[[],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

this is my code, what is the error?

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
83.30000 & 113.69999998714775 & 63.800000003539026 & 127.69999995362014 & 68.80000000819564 & 142.6000000210479 & 67.80000007711351 \\ 40.59999994933605 & 94.90000 & 157.09999995306134 & 70.90000004973263 & 109.69999991357327 & 91.10000007785857 & 50.39999994914979 \\ 64.80000005103648 & 203.099999926053 & 171.2000 & 362.19999997410923 & 97.70000004209578 & 291.4999999338761 & 124.39999997150153 \\ 74.20000003185123 & 90.3000000398606 & 47.599999932572246 & 85.59999 & 157.20000001601875 & 55.00000005122274\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
87.99999998882413 & 70.29999990481883 & 70.90000004973263 & 127.60000000707805 & 41.50000005029142 & 152.29999995790422 & 60.10000000242144\\ 55.19999994430691 & 98.10000006109476 & 122.60000000242144 & 84.09999997820705 & 99.99999997671694 & 101.00000002421439 & 52.00000002514571 \\ 58.8999999454245 & 155.80000006593764 & 126.79999996908009 & 217.2000000718981 & 150.99999543652 & 280.0000000279397 & 117.49999993480742 \\ 79.20000003650784 & 84.60000006016344 & 27.399999904446304 & 78.70000007096678 & 138.09999998193234 & 71.89999998081475\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
90.80000000540167 & 55.500000016763806 & 85.1000000257045 & 126.99999997857958 & 38.59999997075647 & 369.30000002030283 & 109.39999995753169 \\ 50.3000000026077 & 113.80000005010515 & 129.19999996665865 & 75.10000001639128 & 117.49999993480742 & 93.90000009443611 & 47.29999997653067 \\ 68.59999999869615 & 186.80000002495944 & 134.09999990835786 & 272.2000000067055 & 174.60000002756715 & 355.6999999564141 & 97.79999998863786 \\ 19.699999946169555 & 81.70000009704381 & 56.79999990388751 & 88.50000007078052 & 83.89999996870756 & 81.40000002458692\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
124.19999996200204 & 40.29999999329448 & 78.10000004246831 & 131.39999995473772 & 77.30000000447035 & 119.10000001080334 & 91.69999998994172 \\ 26.50000003632158 & 99.50000001117587 & 105.49999994691461 & 98.3634 & 104.90000003483146 & 84.19999992474914 & 53.500000038184226 & 67.7000000141561 \\ 163.3000000147149 & 83.60000001266599 & 190.9999999916181 & 155.70000000298023 & 321.0999999428168 & 97.70000004209578 & 77.09999999497086 \\ 78.1999999890104 & 31.500000040978193 & 78.29999993555248 & 126.30000000353903 & 48.90000005252659\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
98.10000006109476 & 49.20000000856817 & 80.79999999608845 & 106.70000000391155 & 71.0999999428168 & 134.50000004377216 & 74.90000000689179 \\ 47.49999998603016 & 84.20000004116446 & 123.59999993350357 & 86.8999999947846 & 124.40000008791685 & 71.69999997131526 & 46.89999995753169 \\ 64.89999999757856 & 159.10000004805624 & 112.6999999396503 & 225.89999996125698 & 121.29999999888241 & 344.3000001134351 & 97.1999999601394 \\ 88.09999993536621 & 85.70000005420297 & 47.20000002998859 & 82.19999994616956 & 106.49999999441206 & 71.3000000687316\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
103.89999998733401 & 34.20000011101365 & 85.399999981708 & 116.59999995026737 & 71.3000000687316 & 161.79999988526106 & 55.7000000262633 \\ 33.900000038556755 & 93.40000001247972 & 125.20000000949949 & 87.59999996982515 & 112.19999997410923 & 93.60000002197921 & 41.50000005029142 \\ 65.10000000707805 & 187.99999996554106 & 113.69999998714775 & 245.89999997988343 & 169.49999995995313 & 303.5999999847263 & 91.60000004339963 \\ 64.4000000320375 & 84.89999989978969 & 44.10000005736947 & 74.20000003185123 & 82.39999995566905 & 78.10000004246831\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
116.99999996926636 & 25.999999954365194 & 74.6999999973923 & 106.70000000391155 & 55.500000016763806 & 241.79999995976686 & 85.1000000257045 \\ 6.200000061653554 & 105.8999999659136 & 413.99999998975545 & 30.949999985750765 & 562.9999999655411 & 30.550000024959445 & 826.8000000389293 \\ 70.29999990481883 & 75.70000004488975 & 79.60000005550683 & 156.99999989010394 & 82.80000009108335 & 140.00000001396984 & 83.59999989625067 \\ 218.2000000298023 & 64.29999996908009 & 232.7999999979511 & 123.4000000404194 & 264.89999995101243 & 167.30000008828938\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors... oh, I had to put your code inside `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} ... \end{document}`. You know, a minimal example.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your needs? Do you want the inner `bmatrix`-es be stacked vertically? What about the number precision... is that necessary? With it, your construction will necessary fall off the edge of a standard page.

Comment: @Werner 
Can you round to 3 decimal places with latex or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: @Werner 
I want to stack each vector vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s `S[<opt>]` column specification to perform rounding. For simplicity of the code, I've defined a new `BMATRIX` environment that takes care of the specifics with every use case (also for consistency).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\newenvironment{BMATRIX}
  {\left[\hspace{-\arraycolsep}\begin{array}{
    *{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}
    {S[round-precision = 3, round-mode = places]} 
    }}
  {\end{array}\hspace{-\arraycolsep}\right]}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{BMATRIX}
       83.30000           & 113.69999998714775  &  63.800000003539026 & 127.69999995362014  &  68.80000000819564 & 142.6000000210479  &  67.80000007711351 \\
       40.59999994933605  &  94.90000           & 157.09999995306134  &  70.90000004973263  & 109.69999991357327 &  91.10000007785857 &  50.39999994914979 \\
       64.80000005103648  & 203.099999926053    & 171.2000            & 362.19999997410923  &  97.70000004209578 & 291.4999999338761  & 124.39999997150153 \\
       74.20000003185123  &  90.3000000398606   &  47.599999932572246 &  85.59999           & 157.20000001601875 &  55.00000005122274
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
       87.99999998882413  &  70.29999990481883  &  70.90000004973263  & 127.60000000707805  &  41.50000005029142 & 152.29999995790422 &  60.10000000242144 \\
       55.19999994430691  &  98.10000006109476  & 122.60000000242144  &  84.09999997820705  &  99.99999997671694 & 101.00000002421439 &  52.00000002514571 \\
       58.8999999454245   & 155.80000006593764  & 126.79999996908009  & 217.2000000718981   & 150.99999543652    & 280.0000000279397  & 117.49999993480742 \\
       79.20000003650784  &  84.60000006016344  &  27.399999904446304 &  78.70000007096678  & 138.09999998193234 &  71.89999998081475
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
       90.80000000540167  &  55.500000016763806 &  85.1000000257045   & 126.99999997857958  &  38.59999997075647  & 369.30000002030283 & 109.39999995753169 \\
       50.3000000026077   & 113.80000005010515  & 129.19999996665865  &  75.10000001639128  & 117.49999993480742  &  93.90000009443611 &  47.29999997653067 \\
       68.59999999869615  & 186.80000002495944  & 134.09999990835786  & 272.2000000067055   & 174.60000002756715  & 355.6999999564141  &  97.79999998863786 \\
       19.699999946169555 &  81.70000009704381  &  56.79999990388751  &  88.50000007078052  &  83.89999996870756  &  81.40000002458692
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
      124.19999996200204  &  40.29999999329448  &  78.10000004246831  & 131.39999995473772  &  77.30000000447035  & 119.10000001080334 & 91.69999998994172  \\
       26.50000003632158  &  99.50000001117587  & 105.49999994691461  &  98.3634            & 104.90000003483146  &  84.19999992474914 & 53.500000038184226 \\
       67.7000000141561   & 163.3000000147149   &  83.60000001266599  & 190.9999999916181   & 155.70000000298023  & 321.0999999428168  & 97.70000004209578  \\
       77.09999999497086  &  78.1999999890104   &  31.500000040978193 &  78.29999993555248  & 126.30000000353903  &  48.90000005252659
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
       98.10000006109476  &  49.20000000856817  &  80.79999999608845  & 106.70000000391155  &  71.0999999428168   & 134.50000004377216 & 74.90000000689179 \\
       47.49999998603016  &  84.20000004116446  & 123.59999993350357  &  86.8999999947846   & 124.40000008791685  &  71.69999997131526 & 46.89999995753169 \\
       64.89999999757856  & 159.10000004805624  & 112.6999999396503   & 225.89999996125698  & 121.29999999888241  & 344.3000001134351  & 97.1999999601394  \\
       88.09999993536621  &  85.70000005420297  &  47.20000002998859  &  82.19999994616956  & 106.49999999441206  &  71.3000000687316
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
      103.89999998733401  &  34.20000011101365  &  85.399999981708    & 116.59999995026737  &  71.3000000687316   & 161.79999988526106 & 55.7000000262633  \\
       33.900000038556755 &  93.40000001247972  & 125.20000000949949  &  87.59999996982515  & 112.19999997410923  &  93.60000002197921 & 41.50000005029142 \\
       65.10000000707805  & 187.99999996554106  & 113.69999998714775  & 245.89999997988343  & 169.49999995995313  & 303.5999999847263  & 91.60000004339963 \\
       64.4000000320375   &  84.89999989978969  &  44.10000005736947  &  74.20000003185123  &  82.39999995566905  &  78.10000004246831
    \end{BMATRIX} , \\ \\[-.8\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{BMATRIX}
      116.99999996926636  &  25.999999954365194 &  74.6999999973923   & 106.70000000391155  &  55.500000016763806 & 241.79999995976686  &  85.1000000257045  \\
        6.200000061653554 & 105.8999999659136   & 413.99999998975545  &  30.949999985750765 & 562.9999999655411   &  30.550000024959445 & 826.8000000389293  \\
       70.29999990481883  &  75.70000004488975  &  79.60000005550683  & 156.99999989010394  &  82.80000009108335  & 140.00000001396984  &  83.59999989625067 \\
      218.2000000298023   &  64.29999996908009  & 232.7999999979511   & 123.4000000404194   & 264.89999995101243  & 167.30000008828938
    \end{BMATRIX} \phantom{,}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the `round-precision` to something smaller, and play around with `round-mode = figures`. The `S`-type column also ensures proper alignment.

Comment: each vector can not enter a single line?

Comment: @x-rw: You'll have to adjust the font size to accommodate for that and/or decrease the number of digits displayed. Regardless, you'll have to update the syntax to not introduce linebreaks ``\\`` within the inner matrices for that to be the case and update `MaxMatrixCols` to 27 at least.

Comment: i want other question, i should?

Comment: @egreg: Indeed! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One key was using `\\[18pt]` rather than `&` between `bmatrix`es.  In addition, I used `&` before and after each `bmatrix` to give each row 3 columns...in column 1 I placed the opening braket, and in column 3, I placed the closing bracket. All the included `bmatrix`es are placed in column 2.

Of course, I also made it `\tiny` to fit.  Better would be to have the data truncated for each cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\left[\rule{0pt}{15pt}\right.\!\!\!\!\!
&\begin{bmatrix}
83.30000 & 113.69999998714775 & 63.800000003539026 & 127.69999995362014 & 68.80000000819564 & 142.6000000210479 & 67.80000007711351 \\ 40.59999994933605 & 94.90000 & 157.09999995306134 & 70.90000004973263 & 109.69999991357327 & 91.10000007785857 & 50.39999994914979 \\ 64.80000005103648 & 203.099999926053 & 171.2000 & 362.19999997410923 & 97.70000004209578 & 291.4999999338761 & 124.39999997150153 \\ 74.20000003185123 & 90.3000000398606 & 47.599999932572246 & 85.59999 & 157.20000001601875 & 55.00000005122274\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
87.99999998882413 & 70.29999990481883 & 70.90000004973263 & 127.60000000707805 & 41.50000005029142 & 152.29999995790422 & 60.10000000242144\\ 55.19999994430691 & 98.10000006109476 & 122.60000000242144 & 84.09999997820705 & 99.99999997671694 & 101.00000002421439 & 52.00000002514571 \\ 58.8999999454245 & 155.80000006593764 & 126.79999996908009 & 217.2000000718981 & 150.99999543652 & 280.0000000279397 & 117.49999993480742 \\ 79.20000003650784 & 84.60000006016344 & 27.399999904446304 & 78.70000007096678 & 138.09999998193234 & 71.89999998081475\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
90.80000000540167 & 55.500000016763806 & 85.1000000257045 & 126.99999997857958 & 38.59999997075647 & 369.30000002030283 & 109.39999995753169 \\ 50.3000000026077 & 113.80000005010515 & 129.19999996665865 & 75.10000001639128 & 117.49999993480742 & 93.90000009443611 & 47.29999997653067 \\ 68.59999999869615 & 186.80000002495944 & 134.09999990835786 & 272.2000000067055 & 174.60000002756715 & 355.6999999564141 & 97.79999998863786 \\ 19.699999946169555 & 81.70000009704381 & 56.79999990388751 & 88.50000007078052 & 83.89999996870756 & 81.40000002458692\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
124.19999996200204 & 40.29999999329448 & 78.10000004246831 & 131.39999995473772 & 77.30000000447035 & 119.10000001080334 & 91.69999998994172 \\ 26.50000003632158 & 99.50000001117587 & 105.49999994691461 & 98.3634 & 104.90000003483146 & 84.19999992474914 & 53.500000038184226 \\ 67.7000000141561 & 163.3000000147149 & 83.60000001266599 & 190.9999999916181 & 155.70000000298023 & 321.0999999428168 & 97.70000004209578 \\ 77.09999999497086 & 78.1999999890104 & 31.500000040978193 & 78.29999993555248 & 126.30000000353903 & 48.90000005252659\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
98.10000006109476 & 49.20000000856817 & 80.79999999608845 & 106.70000000391155 & 71.0999999428168 & 134.50000004377216 & 74.90000000689179 \\ 47.49999998603016 & 84.20000004116446 & 123.59999993350357 & 86.8999999947846 & 124.40000008791685 & 71.69999997131526 & 46.89999995753169 \\ 64.89999999757856 & 159.10000004805624 & 112.6999999396503 & 225.89999996125698 & 121.29999999888241 & 344.3000001134351 & 97.1999999601394 \\ 88.09999993536621 & 85.70000005420297 & 47.20000002998859 & 82.19999994616956 & 106.49999999441206 & 71.3000000687316\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
103.89999998733401 & 34.20000011101365 & 85.399999981708 & 116.59999995026737 & 71.3000000687316 & 161.79999988526106 & 55.7000000262633 \\ 33.900000038556755 & 93.40000001247972 & 125.20000000949949 & 87.59999996982515 & 112.19999997410923 & 93.60000002197921 & 41.50000005029142 \\ 65.10000000707805 & 187.99999996554106 & 113.69999998714775 & 245.89999997988343 & 169.49999995995313 & 303.5999999847263 & 91.60000004339963 \\ 64.4000000320375 & 84.89999989978969 & 44.10000005736947 & 74.20000003185123 & 82.39999995566905 & 78.10000004246831\end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
&\begin{bmatrix}
116.99999996926636 & 25.999999954365194 & 74.6999999973923 & 106.70000000391155 & 55.500000016763806 & 241.79999995976686 & 85.1000000257045 \\ 6.200000061653554 & 105.8999999659136 & 413.99999998975545 & 30.949999985750765 & 562.9999999655411 & 30.550000024959445 & 826.8000000389293 \\ 70.29999990481883 & 75.70000004488975 & 79.60000005550683 & 156.99999989010394 & 82.80000009108335 & 140.00000001396984 & 83.59999989625067 \\ 218.2000000298023 & 64.29999996908009 & 232.7999999979511 & 123.4000000404194 & 264.89999995101243 & 167.30000008828938\end{bmatrix}&
\!\!\!\!\!\left.\rule{0pt}{15pt}\right]
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]